# Do not understand NavUtils navigation part in Manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-navigation

i was working with back navigation and i found out some code to work with it. In the manifest file i tried to put my packagename and the class name but it says Activity Main does not have a parent acitivity.

Here is my manifest file

the package name is correct: edu.gannon.gannonknightnews

From what i learnt is that parent will be the .Main and the activity i want to go back to is from .NewsFragment. 
I think i did not fully grasped the concept. 
Could you clearify the mistake i have done?

THank you

```
<activity
        android:name="edu.gannon.gannonknightnews.NewsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="edu.gannon.gannonknightnews.Main" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="edu.gannon.gannonknightnews.Main" />
    </activity>
```

and the onoptionsitemselected

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("MENU RETURN","CLICKED");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                //Log.d("MENU RETURN","CLICKED");
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: change `android:parentActivityName="edu.gannon.gannonknightnews.Main"` to `android:parentActivityName=".Main"`

Comment: does not work replacing that

Answer (score 0):

```
android:parentActivityName = " Here give your Activity Name "
```

Don't do anything with `onOptionsItemSelected`.
Back button click event takes automatically.